# Solve for value when expr is a list

Tags: equation-solving

These two lines

```
Solve[t - 5 == 0, t]
Solve[{t - 5} == 0, t]
```

each return `{{t -> 5}}` as expected. However, how do I solve for `t` when the expression becomes a list? Such as:

```
Solve[{t - 5, t + 2} == 0, t]
```

I'll like to have an output similar to `{{t -> 5}, {t -> -2}}` or any other format that yields 5 and -2.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: `Join @@ Solve[# == 0, t] & /@ {t - 5, t + 2}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility is to convert your list into a logical expression:

```
bool = Or @@ Thread[{t-5, t+2} == 0]

Solve[bool, t]
```

> -5 + t == 0 || 2 + t == 0
>
> {{t -> 5}, {t -> -2}}

Comment: I like this solution. Best so far.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking can be done, but it's not the expected form for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html).

Using 
[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`), 
[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and 
[`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) (`#&`)

```
First[Solve[#, t]] & /@ Thread[{t - 5, t + 2} == 0]
```

> ```
> {{t -> 5}, {t -> -2}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you. That helps.